# How to add body to field group?

Tags: 6, entities, nodes

I have installed Fieldgroup module to create groups in node edit form.

However, when I am on Manage fields page (for content type) I cannot add body to a group. Is there any workaround using some hook?

thanks
Tomas

Comment: Body in 6 is not a field via CCK field api, right? If I do remember it right then you simply cannot as body is not a CCK field and fieldgroup holds only CCK fields. Upgrade to 7 or use another text field and treat it as if it was the body. Unless I'm missing how 6 works, haven't used it for way over a year.

Comment: If you can *test* if my memory serves well in this case, then please do so and post a self-answer. I'll be glad to upvote it. Or, if my guess was wrong, tell me I was wrong, I'll be glad to know.

Comment: The only solution I have found was to replace body with CCK field. Yes, body in D6 is not CCK field, and it cannot be threated as CCK in many occasions.

Comment: Consider writing an answer based on that, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I have found was to replace body with CCK field. The body in D6 is not CCK field, and it cannot be threated as CCK in many occasions